# Does anybody have any experience with combining CodedUI with Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, coded-ui-tests

I am writing code to automate a process in a web site which requires smart card authentication and digitally signing documents with a smart card.

Selenium is my tool of choice, but it does not recognize operating system elements as the smart card pop-ups. I thought about using CodedUI (as I develop in C#), but I don't like the tons of code generated by the recorder.

So, my question is: how do you handle OS elements which pop up during a selenium test, [given that you know when to expect them].

Comment: And yet, I have done research on this matter, but failed to find anything helpful. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Then post links to articles, etc. that you have read and why they didn't answer your question. As it is right now, it doesn't look like you've done any research or tried to write any code, etc. to solve your own problem which is going to result in your question getting closed.

Comment: If you find one, I'll be more than happy to post it... I tried.

Answer (score 2):

I'm torn - I think it's really unhelpful to downvote a question in a barren tag like coded-ui. But I also think that this question is a bit broad. Since I hadn't heard of [Winium](https://github.com/2gis/Winium) before just a couple weeks ago I think this deserves an answer.

My team currently uses Winium to moderate effect. Both CodedUI and Winium have horrible performance in complex applications. At least Winium will use familiar syntax.

If you were to use CodedUI I have some suggestions:

- Store all the CodedUI components in a completely separate project. Otherwise you will have horrible testing framework dependency nightmares.
- Use a delegate focused pattern to execute the simple smart card tasks in your various test cases
- Be absolutely sure that you cannot do the smart card interactions with just Selenium
- Once you use a version of CodedUI, NEVER change it. IE if you use 2015 do not change to 2017.
- Investigate how it will affect your run pipelines. Getting it to function correctly is a nightmare.

Comment: I could use WinForm instructions in order to get a specific certificate selected (assuming it is always at the same location in the list), but if I want to create a function which will select a certificate by text, it is very difficult if at all possible. An interesting solution could be using AutoIT. However, I'm trying to stay in the realm of standard .NET and Selenium. Regarding your suggestions, I fully agree. It was very painful to learn them on my own (changing generated code and then, Where on earth did my logic disappear? instead of using the partial class...)